# Is it possible to do redirection without redirecting in browser in PHP?

Tags: php, redirect

```
public function get_api() 
{                                       
    header("Location:$api_call"); 
    //$api call returns nothing, but calls a callback function defined in the $api_call
}
```

I have this code above. Now I must go to browser like `http://domain/get_api` and I'm getting a response within another function function `response_api()` that sets some sessions.

I want the callback function be called, but I don't any output or such. I want to able to do something like:

```
$x = $this->get_api(); //If I do this now I get json response outputted to screen from callback function
//do some stuff after callback function response_api() has been called
```

Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: [curl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)?

Comment: I've tried curl get request, but with no luck.

Comment: can u post the full code? api_call isn't a function

Comment: You are only going to get guess's unless you give more details about what you are trying to do plus more code sample

Answer (score 1):

You can get contents of remote url with:

```
$foo = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/api/something?bar=foo");
```

Comment: hm of course. I tried this before and it didn't seem to work, but now it seems to work. But thanks!!! :-)